# How to add on to a concrete patio?

Tags: concrete, patio

I would like to add on to my existing concrete patio with more concrete. I will about double the size of the patio.

My question is, should I have the new patio free floating from the existing or should I attach it (as in drilling into it and have the rebar go into it)? Is there any proper way to do this?

One edge will be up against the existing patio, another against the brick of the house, and the other two will be open to the yard. Here is a shot that shows the corner between the existing patio and the house:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/extending-concrete-slab

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Great question. Adding this addition requires a really good, deep, compacted base. I would isolate it from the building by 1/2 inch, but if the base is good, rebar to the existing pad will help stop any displacement. You have to expect some settling, but the better the base, the smaller the amount. Web rebar won't help much, but 3/8 or 1/2 inch bar will hold the joint. The trick will be compact, wet, compact, wet. Make it rock hard. Good luck.

Comment: I agree with the first answer, I would consider what is behind the bricks before you pour. Will you ever need to get in their for repairs?

Comment: It is a slabbed house, so the slab is on the other side of the bricks.