# Can I expand a concrete slab by 3/4"?

Tags: concrete

I have an above ground exterior concrete slab that we'd like to surface with 2" x 2" porcelain tiles. The slab is just a little too small – about 3/4" in one dimension. I'm wondering if it would work to build a form around the short end and pour in the missing 3/4" of concrete? I don't think it would be possible to accommodate another full tile (e.g., to add 2 3/4" rather than just 3/4").

Comment: [Related](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/extending-concrete-slab?rq=1). Also, my answer [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/70221/whats-the-proper-way-to-fill-this-hole/70240#70240), describes how to reinforce it with Tapcons instead of bar stock. Another option is to cut the tiles.

Comment: My hope is to not cut the tiles. I've got about 16' so I figure I could mess with the gaps between the tiles, but I'd rather not…

Comment: Assuming 2" tiles over a 16' span, you can make up 3/4" by adding just *.2mm* to each gap.  Wouldn't be noticeable in the least, even if you were looking for it.

Comment: The problem is that the tiles aren't 2" tiles at that level. They come in sheets that are 12" x 24", so I think I'd be looking at making the gaps about 1.2 mm smaller between sheets. The gaps between tiles on the sheets are roughly 3 mm (1/8") so I think that would be noticeable.

Comment: Are you sure those tiles are OK to use on a slab / floor ? Seems like it would be tricky to get enough mortar down to hold them without it coming up between them.  I ran into that using 1 in glass mosaics on a wall. sorry for not answering the question. If you reinforced the joint and used an additive to make sure it sticks, you could probably expand the slab that much.